# Mouse hover over textarea scrollbar gives text cursor instead of default cursor

Tags: css, hover, scrollbar, mouse-cursor

I have a textarea with a scrollbar. I'm aware of that it may only work in webkit browsers, which is fine.

I added `hover` and it did not work as expected. The background turned red which means that the hover works, but the `cursor` does not change.

Am I doing something wrong or may it be Chrome that did not implemented it fully?

**Make sure to click "Run code snippet" to see the demo, or go here: https://jsfiddle.net/k4dm6pgL/**

```css
textarea {
  height: 150px;
  width: 500px;
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 16px;
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #fff;
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover {
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #babac0;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}

textarea::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea>Gingerbread cheesecake bonbon cotton candy cheesecake. Topping pudding ice cream cupcake apple pie pastry caramels. Lemon drops ice cream icing chocolate bar dessert ice cream ice cream. Chocolate cake biscuit cotton candy.

Danish tiramisu tiramisu macaroon fruitcake caramels topping. Halvah oat cake donut. Chocolate cake sugar plum gingerbread jelly cookie. Bear claw marzipan biscuit soufflé donut.

Apple pie chocolate cake tart liquorice pudding sweet roll. Pie gummi bears cake. Dessert apple pie carrot cake tiramisu bear claw.

Danish pie croissant. Cookie halvah lollipop sweet roll gummies wafer marzipan chocolate cake. Caramels chocolate cotton candy cotton candy candy canes. Jelly beans lollipop marzipan chocolate cake chocolate cake cookie.

Dragée bonbon oat cake sweet roll toffee jujubes chocolate cake bear claw sweet. Sesame snaps cupcake pie donut ice cream brownie. Danish carrot cake gummi bears oat cake sweet roll oat cake dessert chocolate cake cake. Caramels tart liquorice.

Gingerbread cheesecake bonbon cotton candy cheesecake. Topping pudding ice cream cupcake apple pie pastry caramels. Lemon drops ice cream icing chocolate bar dessert ice cream ice cream. Chocolate cake biscuit cotton candy.

Danish tiramisu tiramisu macaroon fruitcake caramels topping. Halvah oat cake donut. Chocolate cake sugar plum gingerbread jelly cookie. Bear claw marzipan biscuit soufflé donut.

Apple pie chocolate cake tart liquorice pudding sweet roll. Pie gummi bears cake. Dessert apple pie carrot cake tiramisu bear claw.

Danish pie croissant. Cookie halvah lollipop sweet roll gummies wafer marzipan chocolate cake. Caramels chocolate cotton candy cotton candy candy canes. Jelly beans lollipop marzipan chocolate cake chocolate cake cookie.

Dragée bonbon oat cake sweet roll toffee jujubes chocolate cake bear claw sweet. Sesame snaps cupcake pie donut ice cream brownie. Danish carrot cake gummi bears oat cake sweet roll oat cake dessert chocolate cake cake. Caramels tart liquorice.</textarea>
```

The same thing can be edited here as well: https://jsfiddle.net/k4dm6pgL/

Comment: I cannot see any red background sorry, can you please provide more details about what are you trying to achieve ? **edit: I am using Chrome**

Comment: @Ced Make sure u are using chrome. webkit === chrome

Comment: I am actually but cannot reproduce it

Comment: @Ced Did you click "Run code snippet"? Try the jsfiddle link instead and see if that shows it better.

Comment: @Maurice Did you click "Run code snippet"? Try the jsfiddle link and see if that helps.

Comment: Nah, I'm using firefox. I just wanted to say that chrome is needed.

Comment: @Maurice Yes, Firefox can't be used to run this code.

Comment: @Ced you might be looking at the scrollbar of the frame instead of the `textarea`. Reduce its height and it will appear. :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I found a simple solution, which works fine for me.

Use this:

```
textarea {
    cursor: auto;
}
```

Comment: I wanted the cursor to be the selection I-bar cursor while over the text (which is how it was behaving) but I wanted it to return to the default arrow pointer when over the scrollbar.  This simple to implement CSS did the trick perfectly.

Comment: Works like magic, but isn't the cursor's initial value `auto`? Seems like a browser bug.

Comment: In a real world, the cursor should be text in all the area, not only when hover over text and change for an arrow when going on scrollbars

Answer (score 3):

Currently `cursor` does not seem to be supported for any of the scrollbar elements. This is an expected behaviour for such [*unfinished* properties](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scrollbar).

[This blog post](https://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/) on WebKit mentions several possible customisations, but the cursor is not stated. Other properties such as `visibility: hidden` [are not supported either](https://jsfiddle.net/siavasfiroozbakht/4cmLqwej/16/).

One workaround may be to add a div near your textarea, wrap these two in another div, set the height for the parent div instead, and style the internal div to stay under the scrollbar and set the cursor on it.

Comment: Thanks! Now I can sleep well tonight. I would however not call it a new property as it's been around since 2010. More like an unfinished property. Personally I think they should prioritize it more to get it done.

Comment: You're most welcome @JensTörnell. Totally agree with that, it is available since Chrome version 4 so I'd rather call it unfinished as well :)

Comment: Shall I let it this way or provide a suggestion for a workaround? Your sanity surely matters more than a nice touch on the scrollbar!

Comment: What did you have in mind? I'm already aware of the js libraries that exists. However they are not as stable as the native scrollbar. So I think I'm fine for now.